# How to disable the appearence of the taskbar when a USB is plugged?

Tags: windows, usb, taskbar

I'm developing a software that should be able to "lock" the computer in it, so there will be no chance for any user to return to Windows and use other softwares except if he closes the software using a key (I guess this is what people call to operate in kiosk mode).

After much research I managed to disable Ctrl, Windows Key and Alt using hooks and registry files, so with this I could eliminate (I think) all ways of the user getting away from the software from the keyboard.

But now I found that if somebody plugs an USB device (e.g. a pendrive/data traveler), considering W7, the taskbar immediately apears alongside that traditional dialog where you can choose what you're going to do with the USB device you plugged (open its contents with Explorer, etc.), so somebody can go away from the software apart from the keyboard.

I would like to know how could I stop this, by code or registry (code would be much better!), so if somebody plugs a pendrive the taskbar don't appear and neither that dialog. If I can block USB input from thoose already used (by mouse and keyboard), that could also help.

Btw, if somebody knows of any other tricky way of going away from a kiosk-mode app, tell me!

Thanks,

Momergil

Comment: You forgot disable Sticky keys. User may be able browse from control panel bto anywhere. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you replace `explorer.exe` with your own application in the `Shell` value of the `Winlogon` registry key, your application will be started *instead* of Explorer.  Then all you need to do is disable Task Manager, which can be done via a group policy setting.

The full path to the `Winlogon` key is

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon
```

Comment: Yes, I read about this method of killing explorer.exe, but that is far  away from what I want to do (i.e. the user should have the possibility of going out of the software (giving a key), so I guess explorer can't be killed). The only way of accepting this method would be by opening explorer.exe as soon as the user ask to get away from the software, but I still want to avoid this option. Isn't there any other way?

Comment: I think the dialog you're talking about is an AutoPlay function, so it might go away if you disable AutoPlay.  I believe you can do that with group policy or a registry setting.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just stop **explorer.exe**, disable **Ctrl+Alt+Delete** and **Ctrl+Shift+Esc** to enter kiosk mode?

Comment: Because I want explorer.exe to be running ;) And to disable Ctrl+Alt+Delete is not that simple (the best way I could make it work was through a registry file that requires the computer to be restartet).